# How to get circles generated randomly without overlapping in html5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, kineticjs

i am working on a site in which there are lot of youtube thumbnail images loaded into the circles. And the circles should generate randomly without overlapping. this is the [**Fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/NQpQ5/). not sure of how to load images inside this circles without overlapping in my site. I am using kineticjs. If necessary i can shift to some other code or plugin. Also there is click event for these images. thank u.

```
//js
 var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: Math.random() * stage.getWidth(),
          y: Math.random() * stage.getHeight(),
          radius: Math.random() * 50 + 30,
          fill: Kinetic.Util.getRandomColor(),
          id: id
        });
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to have more than one question here. Are you interested in the circle placement ? The picture rendering ? The click event handling ?

Comment: @dystroy: mainly i need is picture generating inside the circle without overlapping.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach might be to keep an array of the rendered circles as you create them.  Then only add valid (non-overlapping) ones to to the rendering layer.

A circle overlaps with another if the distance between their centers is less than the sum of their radii. In other words, only add Circle2 (with center (x2, y2) and radius r2) if it satisfies the following condition for all pre-existing circles (with centers (x1, y1) and radius r1).

( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ) ^ (1/2) > (r1 + r2)

If it doesn't, discard it and try generating another one.

Comment: There's a very big risk of infinite loop with this approach.

Comment: Yes of course some terminating conditions would be added... something like stopping if a circle can't be added after 3 attempts.  

This should be augmented with intelligent parameter selection, such as ensuring that the radius doesn't exceed a certain proportion of the visible screen, so that an adequate number of circles are usually rendered. 

These parameters should be tweaked until such time as an aesthetically pleasing distribution of circles is more often than not the result. 

At this point we're slipping into the realm of design, rather than programming.

Comment: +1 @NetsydeMiro A variation to keep your circles from "bunching" by random chance: keep an array of well-distributed  center points.  When you need another image, pull the next center point from the array and radius=Math.random()*someMaxRadius+someMinRadius.